# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I'm going to start a new project, I take this error from Android Studio

Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I took this problem since updating the Android Studio.
I don't know what's the problem, but I can open the link mentioned in my browser.
I deleted the Android Studio and installed it again and also installed the previous version for many times but it wasn't resolved.

I put the log file [here](https://files.fm/down.php?cf&i=u2b6fca6&n=idea.log)

Comment: If you have a log, you should either paste it in the question or use a service such as Pastebin (for long text), certainly not shady file sharing sites.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745753/android-stuido-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-get-resource-https-gradle/52757655#52757655

Comment: @KofiNyarko
Really thank you :)
That was my answer and solved my problem