# Android Studio download error maven2 firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

When I build my project in Android Studio, I get [these download errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xERYE.png)

Does anyone know what the problem is?
Thanks for all advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }` in your project level build.gradle file like below any sync again:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745753/android-stuido-gradle-sync-failed-could-not-get-resource-https-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Studio, you should enable Maven repository in Preferences search for Gradle then select Android Studio and tick to `Enable embedded Maven repository`

Other way is add explicitly in your grade

````
``` allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    } } ```
````

Comment: Thanks for answer, we already tried both, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you have `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in the gradle of your project root ?