# gradlew.bat error in downloading gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, proxy, gradlew

I want to run the flutter app on my emulator, but when i click the run button i got this output from gradle in the terminal.

If there is a problem with the image, there is the code:

```
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip


Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

Comment: Open Android module separately in Android Studio and sync Gradle.

Comment: @tyb9900 What do you mean by opening android module seperately?

Comment: Right click on Android Folder, Find Flutter option and you will find the option open in Android Studio.

Comment: @tyb9900 after doing this i got another error: https://pastebin.com/WSdmHj3M

Comment: @tyb9900 There is screenshot of the error tree: https://prnt.sc/pp4dwl

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` and show the screenshot.

Comment: @tyb9900 flutter doctor: https://prnt.sc/pp4len (If it means something - flutter is in C:\src\ but i have not added it to the system path as i have no admin rights on this PC)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused
It will solve your problem.

Comment: @tyb9900 This did not solve the problem but i have another error saying ```ERROR: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'. ```

Comment: can you post the complete android error?

Comment: @tyb9900 but also when i go to proxy settings and setup the proxy and click check connection with this address from the error with the .pom file it says connection successful

Comment: @tyb9900 Event log?

Comment: Yes, Complete event log like you posted before.

Comment: @tyb9900 https://pastebin.com/7ZjumM81

Comment: @OnegaSkiller can you show me your `gradle.properties` file ?

Comment: @tyb9900 https://prnt.sc/ppjwdw

Comment: @tyb9900 One left one is in the project folder the right one is in the gradle home directory under C:/Users/USER/.gradle

Comment: First, make sure you're connected to the internet.
Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52757655/9184784

Comment: @tyb9900 I'm connected to the internet, i have even tested the connection in Android Studio's proxy settings as i mentioned. I under gradle i have only Runner section, i haven't Android Studio section.

Comment: Runner is a complete Android Studio Section.

Comment: there may be an issue with the proxy , as an alternative try downloading the zip in some folder(tools) and use it in gradle-wrapper.properties `distributionUrl=../../../tools/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

Comment: @SHASHISHEKHARBarnwal Okay, this worked, but it searches for .pom file (https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom) i can download it too, but where i have to put it to make it work?

Comment: can you check where is the reference for .pom file? ideally if it is a gradle project it should not look for any maven related files.

Comment: How can i check it? The error does not give me any references.

Comment: @SHASHISHEKHARBarnwal ? ^

Comment: one option is you can search for the file name in notepad++ for all the occurence then you can debug for the main cause